# How to detect if a action listener has been triggered from another class?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I have a method which asks the user a question and in my GUI I have a `JTextArea` where they type in the answer. Since the method which asks the question is in a different class, how would I get the users answer to return to the method?

`GUI` (`JFrame` class):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI extends JFrame{

public GUI(String name) {
    super(name);

    //setSize(700,700);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JPanel myPanel1 = new GUIPanel("Center");
    add(myPanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI frame = new GUI("Game");
}
}
```

`GUIPanel` (`JPanel` class):

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.awt.*;   
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUIPanel extends JPanel {

JLabel label1;
JTextField textField1;
JLabel label2;
JTextArea textArea1;

public GUIPanel(String position) {
    if (position.equals("Center")) {
        createCenterPanel();
    }
}

public void createCenterPanel() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,10,10));

    label1 = new JLabel("Type Here: ");
    textField1 = new JTextField();
    textField1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 25));
    label2 = new JLabel("Game Output: ");
    textArea1 = new JTextArea();

    add(label1);
    add(textField1);
    add(label2);
    add(textArea1);
}
}
```

I have not yet added the method call or `ActionListener` class yet but basically it will call a method which will ask a question and then the user has to answer. This is what I am stuck on. I do not know how I can get the method to "detect" that the user has entered something and then retrieve the data.

I thought about making the textfield static and making a static boolean which gets changed to true when the action performed (user presses enter) gets triggered but that would mean the method would have to have a while loop to check so there must be a better way out there.

Comment: Objects communicate by calling methods, and it is no different for Swing GUI's. If you want to notify another object of a change in state, then call one of its methods. Do ***NOT*** use static anything, and no need to use a boolean.

Comment: *"How to detect if a action listener has been triggered from another class"* The question itself hints at a non-optimal design, and that begins with *"public class GUIPanel **extends JPanel**"*. There is no reason here, to extend a `JPanel`, and it is causing problems by encapsulating components.

Comment: Thank you both for your input, as always it is appreciated. So if I make a method inside the class that checks for change of state (ie action performed triggered) how would I do that because I really have no clue. Really lost with this, sorry if  I do not understand some things. Also Andrew, we were taught that you should extend as it is good practise. If that is not the case as you say, how should I build my GUI because my professor said we will not get marks if it is all in one class.

Comment: Also how is that a non optimal design may I ask. How would one normally get a value from a JComponent (from another class)?

Comment: Your problem would be easier to understand if you showed where you ask the question. This is key since you're trying to share information between this code and the GUI code that you're posting.

Comment: 1)  *"how is that a non optimal design(?)"* Did you carefully **read** the words after *"..and that begins with.."*?
2) Tip: Add @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Yes, what @AndrewThompson said ^^^^. I do have to wonder if the question asking code is part of a linear console program (e.g., one that uses `System.out.println` statements and `new Scanner(System.in)` objects), and that you may be trying to force the two to work together. If so, don't do this since it is painful and frustrating to try to force these two different programming paradigms of event-driven GUI programming and linear console programming together. Again, it would be helpful for you to post your question-asking code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what are you looking for because I don't know if i understood right what do you need but I tried

The only code i added was the method getTextField1Text() and called it inside createCenterPanel(), if you have anything to add please let me know, I hope this helps you a bit

```
    public void createCenterPanel() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10));

            label1 = new JLabel("Type Here: ");
            textField1 = new JTextField();
            textField1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(110, 25));
            label2 = new JLabel("Game Output: ");
            textArea1 = new JTextArea();
            getTextField1Text();

            add(label1);
            add(textField1);
            add(label2);
            add(textArea1);
        }

        public void getTextField1Text() {
            textField1.addActionListener(e -> {
                textArea1.setText(e.getActionCommand());
                textField1.setText("");
            });
        }

-------------------------------------------------------------
```

After discussing in comment section i tried to come up with something
new(which i hope i did) to help you I added 2 methods to get the answer 
(NOTE: I used System.out.println(); only for testing)

These methods are added on GUIPanel class

```
public void getAnswer() {
    textArea1.addActionListener(e -> {
        textArea1.setText(e.getActionCommand());
        testAnswer(textArea1.getText());
    });
}

public String testAnswer(String s) {
    String saveParam = s;
    System.out.println(saveParam);
    return saveParam;
}
```

On GUI class i did some small changes so i can test if the methods is printing the answer,

```
            GUIPanel myPanel1 = new GUIPanel("Center");
            public GUI(String name) {
                super(name);

                //setSize(700,700);
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                setLocationRelativeTo(null);

                add(myPanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);


                pack();
                setVisible(true);
                setResizable(true);
            }

            public GUIPanel getMyPanel1() {
                return myPanel1;
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                GUI frame = new GUI("Game");
                frame.getMyPanel1().getAnswer();

            }
```

Comment: cuda, I really do appreciate this a lot. Thank you so much for this. I have been stuck on it for quite some time and could not find any help on my question. Now one last part that it not answered here. I will have a method from another class that asks the user a question. I want it to be so that once the question is answered (the user triggers the action listener method) it then calls the method that you have created (getTextField1Text()) so that the other class asking the question can retrieve what the user has answered.

Comment: Ignore the above comment, I misread the method you added. Here is the new comment with edits: Now one last part that it not answered here. I will have a method from another class that asks the user a question. I want it to be so that once the question is answered (the user triggers the action listener method) then the code (which I am trying to figure out what it should be) in the action listener essentially sends the value back to the method that is waiting for a answer.

Comment: I edited my post according to what you told me , I tried to help you with my best , I'm a student myself and I know how you feel while you are stuck but I just wish this helps you or you find help from someone else ! Good Luck

Comment: That is wonderful, you are a great contributor to this community and I appreciate it. This works well if I am calling the class from the JFrame class and it is a really great idea. However, do you know how I could use this method if I am calling from a non JFrame class? So to give you an idea of what I am dealing with. I have another class called Teacher and it has a method called introductionLines() were it welcomes to player to the game and asks for a name. The user then types the name into the textArea. How would I get what the user typed into the textArea back to the Teacher class? Thanks!

Comment: @ExileVoid: again, you're fixating on GUI classes somehow being different from non-GUI classes. Don't think in terms of "JFrame class" but simply think in terms of objects and references. You can call a method on any object as long as you have a *reference* to it, no matter if you are in a "JFrame class" or any other class. The key is to pass the reference to where it is needed, and this can be done in the usual ways, such as via a method or constructor parameter.

Comment: @ExileVoid: also as an aside, you really shouldn't have classes extend JFrame unless you need altering the innate behavior of the class in some way by overriding one of its method, a very uncommon requirement. Better to use JFrame objects where needed.

Comment: I'm not really sure and I can't use my pc to try it but try creating a method in teachers class but try something like 
public String/void getStudentName(String s) {
          System.out.println(s); //or return s;
}
And when you call the method
  
teacher.getStudentName(frame.getMyPanel1().textArea.getText());

I assume something like this can work , I hope so good luck !